# Upload files/image with react js to parse cloud/class?

Tags: file-upload, parse-platform, reactjs

I have been strugling to upload files (images) to parse cloud and save it in my parse class. I cannot find proper documentation on how does this work.

Here is my upload form component/class (ES6, React-Parse, React, i connected to parse via parent components) ):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Parse } from 'parse';
import ParseReact from 'parse-react';
import mui from 'material-ui';
import { TextField, RaisedButton } from 'material-ui';

class AddChallenge extends React.Component{

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      imageFile: '',
    };
  }

  _onUpload(e) {

    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var parseFile = new Parse.File('image-name', file);
    console.log(parseFile);
    this.state.imageFile = parseFile;
  }


  _addChallenge(){
    // this.preventDefault();
    var theme = this.refs.theme.getValue(); //take value
    var timespan = this.refs.timespan.getValue(); //take value
    timespan = parseInt(timespan) * 86400;
    var parsefile = this.state.imageFile;
    console.log(parsefile);


    // Passing data to parse
    parsefile.save().then(function() {
      // The file has been saved to Parse.
      console.log('was saved?');
    }, function(error) {
      // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
    });

    console.log(parsefile.url());

    ParseReact.Mutation.Create("Challenge", {
      theme: theme,
      timespan: timespan,
      archived: false,
      active: true
    }).dispatch().then(function() {
    });
  }

  render() {
    let style = {
      input: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '0',
        bottom: '0',
        right: '0',
        left: '0',
        width: '100%',
        opacity: '0',
      }
    }

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this._addChallenge.bind(this)}>
        <TextField
          ref="theme"
          hintText="ex Weekend Drunkster"
          floatingLabelText="Title" />
        <br />
        <TextField
          ref="timespan"
          hintText="1"
          floatingLabelText="Duration (days)" />
        <br />

        <RaisedButton label="Choose an Image">
          <input type="file" id="uploader" ref="uploader" onChange={this._onUpload.bind(this)} style={style.input}></input>
        </RaisedButton>
        <br />

        <RaisedButton label="Submit" primary={true}>
          <input type="submit" value="Post" style={style.input} />
        </RaisedButton>
      </form>

    );
  }
}
export default AddChallenge;
```

Parse `save()`is based on [parse.file documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.File.html), but as i understand i use it wrong. Even though `then()`function prints my log (as if it was saved).

In general, how to save image to parse class ?

Comment: Is this really related to React, or do you merely happen to use React and this is a general Parse question? (I am unsure as I haven't used Parse, but it does seem so to me.)

Comment: well it is parse related, but i dont know how to achieve this via react (parse-react). In addition, maybe someone will suggest a better way to do that via react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your object up in the observe, in this case I have a custom Parse object called `Event` which has a column called `primaryPhoto` which is where I will save the `Parse.File` Object

```
observe: function () {
    return {

        event: (new Parse.Query('Event'))
            .equalTo('objectId', this.getParams().eventId),
    }
},
```

Now here is the code to save image and associate with event object

```
_handleSaveImage: function() {
    var imageFile = new Parse.File("mypic.jpg", {base64: this.state.preview});
    var that = this;

    return imageFile.save().then(function () {

        return ParseReact.Mutation.Set(that.data.event[0], {'primaryPhoto':imageFile}).dispatch();

    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(error);
    });
},
```